How to create a wrapper around `fixest::etable()`?
I am trying to create a wrapper function around fixest::etable() but get an error message even in the simplest case:
library(fixest)

mod <- feols(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

my_etable <- function(...) {
  etable(...)
}

my_etable(mod)
#> Error: in etable(...): 
#> Argument `headers` could not be evaluated: ... used in a situation where it
#> does not exist

Created on 2024-05-27 with reprex v2.1.0
It does work when I capture the dots argument as a list:
my_etable <- function(...) {
  m <- list(...)
  etable(m)
}

However, this prevents me from passing arguments other than the model to etable(). Ideally, I would like to run something like my_etable(mod, se.below = TRUE). Additionally, capturing the dots as a list prevents me from passing a list of models to my wrapper function (which would be possible with etable() itself).

Have you tried using match.args?

I haven't – could you explain how I should use it here?

It seems we need to make a modification at the level of expressions:
library(fixest)

mod <- feols(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

my_etable <- function(..., se.below = TRUE) {
  expr <- substitute(etable(..., se.below = se.below))
  eval(expr)
}

my_etable(mod)
#>                        mod
#> Dependent Var.:        mpg
#>                           
#> Constant        29.60***  
#>                 (1.230)   
#> disp            -0.0412***
#>                 (0.0047)  
#> _______________ __________
#> S.E. type              IID
#> Observations            32
#> R2                 0.71834
#> Adj. R2            0.70895
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

my_etable(mod, se.below = FALSE)
#>                                 mod
#> Dependent Var.:                 mpg
#>                                    
#> Constant           29.60*** (1.230)
#> disp            -0.0412*** (0.0047)
#> _______________ ___________________
#> S.E. type                       IID
#> Observations                     32
#> R2                          0.71834
#> Adj. R2                     0.70895
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

my_etable(mod, se = "hetero", se.below = FALSE)
#>                                 mod
#> Dependent Var.:                 mpg
#>                                    
#> Constant           29.60*** (1.480)
#> disp            -0.0412*** (0.0051)
#> _______________ ___________________
#> S.E. type       Heteroskedast.-rob.
#> Observations                     32
#> R2                          0.71834
#> Adj. R2                     0.70895
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-05-28 with reprex v2.1.0
Alternatively, setFixest_etable() can be used instead of a wrapper function to set defaults.
